# Pointwise convergence in probability and maximum of finite random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{G_n(\theta)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables indexed by $\theta\in\Theta$.
> Suppose that
> $$
>  \forall\theta\in\Theta, G_n(\theta) \to_p 0 \quad(\text{pointwise convergence}).
>  $$
>
> Pick any finite indices $\{\theta \}_{j=1}^J \subset \Theta$. Show that, for any
> $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$,
>
> $$
>  \varlimsup_{n\to \infty} P(\max_{j\le J} |G_n (\theta_j)|>\varepsilon_1) < \varepsilon_2.\qquad (\ast)
>   $$

I encountered this proposition in a paper. The expression (*) is (I think) equivalent to $\max_{j\le J} |G_n (\theta_j)| \to_p 0$. Since an index $\theta_j$ that gives maximum may differ for each $n$, it is hard to see how I can use  the assumption.

Of course, it is obvious that $P(G_n (\theta)) \le P(\max_{j\le J} G_n(\theta_j)) $, but how can I bound $P(\max_{j\le J} G_n(\theta_j))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\max_{j \leq J} G_n(\theta_j) >\epsilon_1) \leq \sum_{j \leq J} P(G_n(\theta_j) >\epsilon_1)$ because $\max_{j \leq J} G_n(\theta_j)>\epsilon_1$ implies $G_n(\theta_j) >\epsilon_1$ for some $j$. Since each term in the finite sum $\sum_{j \leq J} P(G_n(\theta_j) >\epsilon_1)$ tends to $0$ it follows that the entire sum tends to $0$.

(Actually $\lim\sup P(\max_j G_n(\theta_j) >\epsilon_1)=0$ and hence it is less than $\epsilon_2$).